# Limit of sequence with floor function

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$
\mbox{How do I compute}\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}%
\left\lfloor\sqrt[4]{\vphantom{\Large A}n^{4} + 4n^{3}}-n\right\rfloor\ {\large ?}
$$

I know that could use squeeze theorem, but for that I would need to find two sequences, which I don't know how to find. For floor function I know that I can somehow use $x - 1 < \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \leq x$.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Clearly
$$
n^4 < n^4 + 4 n^3 < n^4 + 4 n^3 + 6 n^2 + 4 n + 1 = (n+1)^4.
$$
Therefore 
$$
n < \sqrt[4]{n^4 + 4 n^3} < n + 1.
$$
Thus 
$$
0 < \sqrt[4]{n^4 + 4 n^3} - n < 1. 
$$
Hence 
$$
\left\lfloor \sqrt[4]{n^4 + 4 n^3} - n \right\rfloor = 0
$$
for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If you just extract "$n$" from the radical, it becomes $n \left(1 + \frac{4}{n}\right)^{1/4}$. This is always greater than "$n$" but the term $1 + \frac{4}{n}$ is smaller and smaller and goes to zero when "$n$" increases more and more. So, the radical becomes closer and closer to "$n$" and so the limit is zero as shown in the previous answers.

Comment: As n approaches infinity the term (1+4/n)^1/4 converges to zero?I am confused, I thought that limit of this term is 1 (limit of 4/n is 0, but still there is number 1)

Comment: @cryogenic.Sorry !!! converges to 1 and only 1. I apologize for the typo (I am almost blind and I do not see what I type). Sorry again for the confusion. Cheers.

Comment: ok, so basically I got the limit of sequence $ \sqrt[4]{n^{4}+3n^{3}}-n $, but what about the floor function?

Comment: You need the floor of [n + epsilon - n] and epsilon is small, positive but not 0. Then .... 0

Comment: I am sorry, I am slow to understand, could you please explain it a bit? In theory I know a little bit about floor function,but I have never evaluated a limit with floor function in it. Thank you

Comment: Let us try with numbers. What is the floor of (10 + 0.1 - 10) ?

Comment: Is it 0? The way I understand is [3.4]=3, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: So now with a limit, you said we have  [n + epsilon - n], in our case that n is a limit we evaluated? [(n^4+3n^3)^1/4 + epsilon - (n^4+3n^3)^1/4], what about the epsilon?

Comment: @cryogenic. What I tried to show is that, after extracting "n" from the radical, the radical itself decreases more and more and goes to 1 by positive values. So, the result you look for is the floor of [n (1 + small_number) - n] which is zero.

Comment: Ah thank you!I understand it now

Comment: I really would appreciate to know why downvotes

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just accepted different answer, which I liked more, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with yours, I hope you understand, I still appreciate you taking time to answer me.(there was a new answer yesterday)

Comment: @cryogenic. I did not tell it was you. My answer was rejected and it is the first time I see that happening. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use $$a^4-b^4=(a-b)(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3)$$

$$(n^4+4n^3)^{\frac14}-(n^4)^{\frac14}=\frac{n^4+4n^3-n^4}{(n^4+4n^3)^{\frac34}+(n^4+4n^3)^{\frac24}n+(n^4+4n^3)^{\frac14}n^{^2}+n^3}$$

Now divide the numerator & the denominator by $n^3$

---

Alternatively, set $\frac1n=h$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }[\sqrt[4]{n^{4}+4n^{3}}-n]=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(1+4h)^{\frac14}-1}h$$

Now applying Taylor's expansion $$(1+4h)^{\frac14}=1+\frac h4+O(h^2)$$

Comment: Oh I am sorry! I got the wrong number in it. I just edited it.Well with that though what I got is $\frac{4}{\sum_{i=0}^{3}\sqrt[4]{1+\frac{4}{n}}^{3-i}}$

Comment: it should be correct now it is 4n^3 instead of 3n^3.

Comment: @user113243, please find the  edited version

Comment: We haven't covered Taylor expansion yet. So I am afraid I don't know how to use it. Using the first method you mentioned I get a fraction within floor function, I can just take a limit of what is inside? And then use floor function on it?

Comment: Or, even simpler, by applying [Newton's binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), $(n+1)^4=n^4+4n^3+O(n^2)$. :-)

Comment: @Lucian, not sure where you have found $(n+1)^4$